Mutual Information of two conditionally independent varibales given other varibale
I have data as $X$ which has two independent labels as $Y$ and $M$. So the goal is to process the $X$ to $Z_1=\mathcal{F}_1(X)$ to maximize $I(Z_1;Y|M)$. We know that:
$$I(Z_1;Y|M) = I(Z_1;Y) - I (Z_1;Y;M)$$
So I can maximize the first part, and minimize the second.
My question is, instead of minimizing $I(Z_1;Y;M)$, can I maximize $I(Z_2;Y;M)$ and using auxiliary $Z_2=\mathcal{F}_2(X)$ which is orthogonal to $Z_1$ ($Z_1 \perp Z_2$)?
$$ I(Z_1;Z_2)=0$$
More precise is it correct:
$$\min I(Z_1;Y;M) \Longleftrightarrow \max(Z_2;Y;M) \;\; s.t. \;\; I(Z_1;Z_2)=0$$

I think the first equation should be $I(Z_1;Y|M) = I(Z_1;Y,M) - I (Z_1;M)$
Further, what does this mean? "X has two independent labels as Y
and M"
